# Suggestions for repairing disintegrating concrete blocks in garage?

Tags: repair, garage, concrete-block

[image: Damaged concrete blocks in garage]
Our garage has a row of filled concrete blocks that are tied to the foundations, upon which the sill plate is attached. One corner has begun to let in water, and the freeze/thaw cycles of our Minnesota fall/winter/spring have done some pretty significant damage to the blocks (some mold there too, but let's take this one crisis at a time...)

I've addressed the water issue (knock on wood), but I'm baffled about what to do about those damaged blocks. Can I simply clean out the damaged bits, set up forms, and pour fresh concrete in there? Other suggestions?

Comment: Does the corner need to be jacked up before the repairs can be made? Otherwise, that corner would be lower, afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you could pour concrete, but why not just jack up the sill and reinstall cinder blocks? Seems like a simple and cheap idea. Harbor Freight sells air-operated hydraulic jacks, which I use all the time to raise houses while replacing joists, columns, sill plates, etc. The difficult part will be installing the last block, since you have to jack up the house just a tad taller than the cinder block, then let the sill down. There are many ways to do this, depending on the access you have to "grab" the wall and raise it with the jack.

Comment: Are empty cinder blocks rated as load-bearing?   I always though the blocks were a tough weather resistant exterior for the concrete and rebar inside, but are vulnerable to impact when not mortered together and filled with concrete ?

Answer (score 1):

You've done the right thing by fixing the water issue first.  Are you positive that's resolved and won't come back ?

If it were me, I'd jack up the whole corner by an inch or two, then bust out the broken blocks for a short stretch.

Build some forms to hold concrete and secure them in place in such a way you can pour concrete, and its strong enough not to bust out due to weight of wet concrete.

It may be prudent to consult an engineer - there could be insurance issues if this is not done up to code with rebar/reinforcing-rod and tying that back into the known-good foundation (if any) and into the floor.

You want the final top level of the concrete to be the same height as the existing block but you need some room to pour concrete in, and to get it levelled on top and vibrated into place.   If you just "shove concrete in the hole" it won't be quite high enough.

You might only do one corner done at a time, and wait a week to set then peel off the forms and prepare to pour the next section.

For some additional examples, watch through this playlist of Diesel Creek Matt reworking some foundations.   https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=diesel+creek+church+concrete+wall+pour

---

On the other hand, if you have the lifting capacity it may be easiest to raise the entire garage and pour the new concrete ring foundation all at once. This will allow for continuous sticks of rebar.   Then lower garage back down.

Aside - this would probably end up being a "cripple-wall" instead of a "ring foundation"